# image swiping not working in android view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture, photoswipe

I want to create an app which swipe images left/right so i use viewPager for this i run this code it gets run successfully but blank screen comes nothing happens.

This is my homeSwipe Class

```
             public class homeSwipe extends Activity {
                    ViewPager viewPager;
                customPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_swipe);
                        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                       customPagerAdapter = new customPagerAdapter(homeSwipe.this);
                       viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
                    }

                }
```

that is my layout.xml:

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pager">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my customPagerAdapter class

```
        public class customPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private int imgres[] ={R.drawable.graypatternbackground,R.drawable.home,R.drawable.homescreen,R.drawable.redwall};
            private Context context;
            private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            public customPagerAdapter(Context context){
                this.context =context;
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {

                return imgres.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return (view == (LinearLayout)object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                layoutInflater =  (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View   item_view =(View)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipelayout,container,false);
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imgView.setImageResource(imgres[position]);
                return item_view;
            }
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
            }
        }
```

This is my swipelayout.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try this tutorial http://blog.sqisland.com/2012/09/android-swipe-image-viewer-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

```
This is custompagerAdapter.
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
public class PropTypePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   int noOfTab;
     public PropTypePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm ,int noOfTab) {
      super(fm);
  this.noOfTab=noOfTab;
 }
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
                  return new PropTabType(0);
    case 1:
                 return new PropTabType(1);
    case 2:
                 return new PropTabType(2);
    case 3:
                PropTabType service = new PropTabType(3);
                return service;
    }
 }
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
         return noOfTab;
  }
 }
And this is logic for swapping image
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prop_type_tab,container, false);
fragImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragImg);
         if (position == 0) {
                   fragImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.buy);
              } else if (position == 1) {
                   fragImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.rent1);
               } else {
                   fragImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.hostel);
          }
       return view;
 }
```

Comment: you are written code in instantiate() but there is wrong way because it called once